# MFC messageloop in dialog window

Tags: c++, mfc, tray, message-loop

i created a MFC dialog application.

now i want to use a messageloop, but i can not find it. I read that mfc will create it for me but that it will be hidden. so how can i manipulate the messageloop?

i need the messageloop to recieve events from my tray icon which i created for that application.

so that i can use something like that:

```
long CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT nMsg, UINT wParam, LONG lParam) 
{ 
   switch(nMsg) 
   { 
   case (WM_USER + 1): 
      { 
         switch(lParam) 
         { 
         case WM_RBUTTONUP: 
            { 
               /**/
            } 
         } 
         return 0; 
      } 

   default: 
      return DefWindowProc(hWnd, nMsg, wParam, lParam); 
   } 
}
```

I'm still a beginner at mfc.

Comment: Do not worry about the message loop (Behind the scene stuff). Search for and learn how to you make message map entries and process the messages sent by the tray icon...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After installing an icon to the system tray by Shell_NotifyIcon, this icon become the extension of your dialog UI. When the user interact with this icon, the UI messages will be re-directed to your dialog by the OS automatically.

To serve these user messages you needs to perform few steps:

(1) Add a message handler definition (ON_MESSAGE(WM_TRAY_NOTIFY, OnTrayNotify)) inside the (.cpp) file. Must be inside the BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP/END_MESSAGE_MAP block:

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CTestDlg, CDialog)
   //{{AFX_MSG_MAP(CTestDlg)
   ON_WM_PAINT()
   ON_WM_QUERYDRAGICON()
   ...
   //}}AFX_MSG_MAP
   ON_MESSAGE(WM_TRAY_NOTIFY, OnTrayNotify)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

(2) Add a message handler implementation in the (.cpp) file, to perform the actual work

```
void CTestDlg::OnTrayNotify(UINT nID, LPARAM lEvent)
{
    if (nID==TRAYICON_ID1)
    {   
        // handle messages here
        if (lEvent==WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK)
        {  // do left button double click, usually restore application
        }
        if (lEvent==WM_RBUTTONUP)
        {  // do right button up, usually popup a menu at clicked location
        }
    }
}
```

(3) Add a prototype definition of this message handler (afx_msg void OnTrayNotify(UINT nID, LPARAM lEvent);) inside the (.h) file. Must be inside the BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP/END_MESSAGE_MAP block:

```
// Generated message map functions
//{{AFX_MSG(CTestDlg)
virtual BOOL OnInitDialog();
afx_msg void OnPaint();
afx_msg HCURSOR OnQueryDragIcon();
...
//}}AFX_MSG
afx_msg void OnTrayNotify(UINT nID, LPARAM lEvent);
DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

(4) Add definition inside (.h) file

```
#define WM_TRAY_NOTIFY WM_USER+567
#define TRAYICON_ID1 0x1234
```

The code above is assuming:

- The dialog name is CTestDlg, change it to your dialog name
- The user-callback-message identifier (uCallbackMessage) used to setup Shell_NotifyIcon is WM_TRAY_NOTIFY
- The identifier of the tray icon (uID) sed to setup Shell_NotifyIcon is TRAYICON_ID1